# Find and run script from another directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a script, say `data.sh`,  which takes many data files in the same directory and process them. I have many directories with different files but I have the same script in all. I can routinely go to each dir and execute `data.sh` by `./data.sh` but it is tedious.

- How can I run `data.sh` from the parent dir? My first guess of ./parent/dir1/data.sh does not work.
- I'd like to excecute all `data.sh` scripts simultaneously. How? I can find all `data.sh` by find command in the parent dir: `find . -name data.sh`.  How to `-exec` with them? The following has the same problem as in my first point:

  ```
  find . -name data.sh -exec ./{} \;
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to change `data.sh` and make it accept one or more arguments, those being the files (and perhaps directories) being worked on.

Say the script currently contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
some-command ./*    # ← this is where it works on all files
```

Then you'd change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
some-command "$@"
```

Here, `$@` is all arguments passed to `data.sh`, and you'd only need to call it like this:

```
/path/to/data.sh /path/to/another/directory/*
```

Then the script would run on all files in the other directory. Of course, without knowing the exact inner workings of `data.sh` it's impossible to suggest how to change it, specifically.

---

If you want to keep `data.sh` as-is, you need to change the current directory every time you call it. This will make your script "think" it's inside another directory.

You could achieve this by using `cd` (or `pushd`/`popd`) from a shell launched by `find`:

```
find . -name "data.sh" -exec sh -c 'cd "$(dirname "$0")" && ./data.sh' {} \;
```

Or you could temporarily `cd` the directory in a subshell (this is the parentheses around `cd`), maybe with globs so you can skip using `find` (the `**` will recursively match all directories):

```
shopt -s globstar
for script in **/data.sh; do
    ( cd "$(dirname "$script")" && ./data.sh )
done
```

If you hadn't used a subshell in the above command, the second `cd` call would fail since it'd try to `cd` from the first found directory that contains `data.sh`. You can avoid this with `pushd`/`popd`:

```
for script in **/data.sh; do
    pushd "$(dirname "$script")" && ./data.sh
    popd
done
```

Comment: WOW! I REALLY appreciate your super detailed and helpful comment. This was exactly the one I was hoping to get. I tested your 2nd option (with find command ) and worked like charm. But I learned also a great deal by the other ways.